# mtry value depends on tuneGrid range even with the same seed

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, party

I am trying to find the optimal mtry value for conditional random forest. I do it with the help of caret::train function and found that depending on the grid range I got different optimal mtry even with the same seed. Which value shall I pick then?
Example:

1. with the below code I got mtry=8

```
set.seed(12)
data<-mtcars%>%
     mutate(target=as.factor(vs))
grid <- expand.grid(.mtry=2:12)
mod <- train(target ~ ., data = data, method = "cforest", controls = cforest_unbiased(ntree = 500), tuneGrid=grid)
mod$bestTune
```

2. while with the grid 1:12 I got mtry=9

```
set.seed(12)
data<-mtcars%>%
     mutate(target=as.factor(vs))
grid <- expand.grid(.mtry=1:12)
mod <- train(target ~ ., data = data, method = "cforest", controls = cforest_unbiased(ntree = 500), tuneGrid=grid)
mod$bestTune
```

Comment: You're changing the tuning values, so it doesn't seem to me to be a big surprise that it may return different results. I'm not a pro with `caret`, but why do you feel that different `tuneGrid` should produce the same results?

Comment: @r2evans for me it looks like the algorithm is unstable

Comment: Interesting. I'm voting to migrate this question to [stats.se] where the theoretical discussion is more appropriate. I hope it gets the attention and discourse you hope it does!

Comment: @r2evans okay, will post there

Comment: I think this is just a computational and not a conceptual issue. Hence I decided to answer it here rather than on CV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the grid differs, then in general the results will differ, even for the same seed. It will depend, however, on how the `train()` function goes through the grid. Possibly, if you just change the end (rather than the beginning) of the grid, then the results up to that point will be the same.

If you want to split up computations, then you could use separate grids and set separate seeds before training on each one of them. Then you can easily add or drop parts. But, of course, you will have to select the best result manually over the different grids.

Getting an `mtry = 8` vs `mtry = 9` does not seem to be a huge difference anyway. I wouldn't be surprised if this is within the range of random variation here. But I couldn't replicate your results because I just got warnings from the training (possibly because `vs` is identical to `target` but is used as one of the regressors).